# Scripts not working on Tumblr page embedded in iFrame?

Tags: java, iframe, tumblr

First up - apologies, I've researched the site, and while *think* I may have seen an answer, my lack of talent lets me down.

I have embedded a tumblr page into an iframe and everything looks fine, however the tumblr theme uses java for a 'cargo' stye layout, and now the column won't expand when you click on the grid.

From what I understand, the iframe won't allow the java to run (they are on different domains) so I would like to know if there is a way of referencing the scripts in the iframe to enable them to run?

I'm afraid I am not a programer, more of a half talented cut and paster of bits and pieces, so please speak slowly to the idiot child.